# R - Input a df and column into a function

Tags: r, function

I want to create an user defined function that takes a df and column (col_name) as arguments and creates the following columns: standard deviation, average, upper bound, lower bound. The metrics for the created columns should be the same value for all observations. The dataframe currently has Date, Sales, and Assets columns.

```
outlier_graph <- function(df, col_name){
 df$standard_dev <- sd(df$col_name)
 df$avgerage_obs <- mean(df$col_name)
 df$upper_bound <- df$avgerage_obs + (df$standard_dev * 1.96)
 df$lower_bound <- df$avgerage_obs - (df$standard_dev * 1.96)

##then I want the function to return a graph and/or the df

 g <- ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(date, upper_bound)) + 
   geom_line(aes(date, upper_bound)) +
   geom_point(aes(date, col_name))
 g

return(df)
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [dplyr::mutate()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html).

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Try using `df[[col_name]]` to avoid non-standard evaluation issues

Comment: If you aren't into `dplyr`, base R's `transform` is fairly decent, too, though the `dplyr::mutate_*` variants bring a lot of versatility and power.

Comment: I tried the mutate, nut it is not identifying the col_name:   Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'ted_spread' not found

Comment: Also, when I used the double bracket df[[col_name]], I get this error:                     Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'ted_spread' not found

Comment: after you replace all `df$col_name` with `df[[col_name]]`. Call the function using `outlier_graph(df, "col_name")`